# Connecting to Weblogic JMS Queue from a non java application

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have a Weblogic JMS Server. I want to post Message to the JMS queue of that server  from another server not having any application Server.

I have got some link which states we can directly Instantiate JMS Resources Without Using JNDI . By Using Hornet Q / Active MQ.

Any  example will be a great help..

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with HornetQ or ActiveMQ.

if you google for that you can easily find how to do it for ActiveMQ or HornetQ.

Comment: And do you literally mean non-java or just non J2ee container? Without using JNDI or JNI? Two very different things... Simple java client: http://redstack.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/a-simple-jms-client-for-weblogic-11g/